# Latest Post Styled Different Than other Posts

Tags: loop, featured-post

I'm just completely mixed-up with this.
I need the 1st post of the loop looks differently,
as a kind of magazine style, you know: bigger thumbnail
and bigger title.

I tried already nth-of-type in CSS, :first-child, and
different php variations.
But nothing works.

Here is the main part of code on index.php::

```
<h3 class="latest">The Latest</h3>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post excerpt <?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" id="featured-thumbnail"></a>

<div class="post-content-inner">
<header>    
<div class="img-container">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail('slider',array('title' => '')); echo '</div>'; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="info-container">
<h2 class="title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>
<div class="post-info">
<span class="thetime"><span class="icon-clock" style="margin-right:-4px;"></span>
<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?> </span>
</div>

</div>
</header><!--.header-->

<div class="post-content image-caption-format-1">
<!--<?php echo excerpt(48);?>-->
</div>

</div>
</div><!--.post excerpt-->
```

I'll be tremendously appreciate if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the default loop (not a custom one), you can check the counter for the first (0th) loop and alter your output just for that one.

The WordPress support forum had [a similar question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/target-first-post-in-loop#post-3234154) that offered this bit of code:

```
if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { /*first post*/ }
```

You can put your whole block of HTML inside that `if` statement with your customization, or use it to just add classes to the elements for styling with CSS. For example, something like this could work:

```
$first_post = false;
if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { 
    $first_post = true;
}
// inside The Loop:
<div class="post excerpt <?php if( $first_post ) { echo 'first-post'; } ?>">
```

That would give you `class="post excerpt first-post"` on the first one and `class="post excerpt "` on the others. You can do this in addition to your other custom classes that are in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I would make sure its not a specificity issue try

```
html body.someclass div.somewrapperClass div.post etc...
```

As many levels as you can just to check if its not simply a css issue.